# Android videoview playable logo

Tags: android, video

Hi my android coding have a videoview and I want to put playable logo overlay on it when it's stop but when it's playing the logo disappear, how can I do it?

here is my coding on videoview

```
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.complete));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                    videoView.pause();
                } else {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```